# Ng-Table, ng-repeat on td element doesnt show column header

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am using ng-repeat on  element in the table to show multiple columns, i have used data-title attribute to see the column header, but with ng-repeat it just shows column header for first column, but not the rest of the column,

please check the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Ex0XPCCKhRzRlzkfVmhG?p=preview

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
  <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
    <td data-title="'Name'">
      {{user.name}}
    </td>
    <td data-title="'Age'" ng-repeat="a in user.age">
      {{a}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

'Age' header is not shown for all column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find the answer for it, but a workaround is available at 
http://plnkr.co/edit/Ex0XPCCKhRzRlzkfVmhG?p=preview

```
 <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
   <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td ng-repeat="a in $data[0].age">Age</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
  <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
    <td>
      {{user.name}}
    </td>
    <td ng-repeat="a in user.age">
      {{a}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

just created the separate element for header and added that many columns

Comment: I m into same issue. but your suggested answer wont provide default ng-table header behaviour for sorting and advance search coz you are creating your tables headers yours own. I need to achieve default ng-table headers title dynamically, any other possible solution please?